# Rotate a line around a circle in three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

```
var lineGeometry  = new THREE.Geometry();
var lineMaterial = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({
    color: 0x000000
});
lineGeometry.vertices.push(
    new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0),
    new THREE.Vector3(0, 10, 0),
);
var line = new THREE.Line(lineGeometry, lineMaterial);
scene.add(line);
```

I want to update this line's endpoint in a circular fashion. In other languages it is straightforward, I would increase some variable and update the endpoint like radius * cos(dt) and radius * sin(dt). In three.js I tried the following, but it doesn't work:

```
var dt = 0;
function render(){
    dt += 0.01;
    line.geometry.vertices[1].x = 10*Math.cos(dt);
    line.geometry.vertices[1].z = 10*Math.sin(dt);
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
    requestAnimationFrame(render);
}
```

**edit:** I don't want to use `line.rotation.z += 0.01` method.

Comment: Try to add `line.geometry.verticesNeedUpdate = true;` before `renderer.render(scene, camera);` in the `render` function.

Comment: Oh that worked, thanks for your time!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
line.geometry.verticesNeedUpdate = true;
```

Add the above line before calling `render`. This will signal three.js that the vertex buffer has changed, so it will update it appropriately.

Since you mentioned using `line.rotation`, I must mention that updating the vertices is inefficient compared to rotating the line shape. When you rotate a line shape, you are simply updating the shape's transformation matrix. But when you update vertices, three.js needs to re-upload the entire set of vertices to the GPU. This may seem trivial for a single line segment, but it's a bad habit to get into if you ever intend to use larger shapes later.

Comment: That really depends on your use case. If you have 100 lines all moving it would be much more performant to put them all in a single LineSegment and update them directly then to make 100 line segments and use transation, rotation, and scale.

Comment: @gman "That really depends on your use case," should be the first line of every answer on SO. :)